# Implications of deeply nested arrays/objects, and suggested language/data models to use

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I've developed the need to generate a single epic array. It would look fairly standard to begin with, something like:

```
epic = {
    0 : "epic parent"
    1 : {
        0 : "bob child",
        1 : {
            0 : "mary grand-child",
            1 : {
                0 : "jane great-grand-child",
                etc. (e.g. down to "john (great*1000)-grand-child")
            }
        },
        2 : {
            etc.
        }
    },
    2 : {
        etc.
    }
    etc.
}
```

But then the thing is, it has the potential to grow to huge depths. Likely getting into hundreds if not thousands of levels deep, as well as of course potentially very wide. The reason for this, is that any one new entry could equally be added as a direct child of ANY existing point, be it `epic[1]` or `epic[1][21][41][661][3][72][8543][22][1][2][etc.]`

My question is, what are the implications with building a single 'epic' array like this? Are there differences in how huge/DEEP arrays are processed in the different languages? Would some languages be better suited to this than others? How would this array best be stored?

The easiest way to exemplify this is perhaps to imagine storing an entire family tree starting from a single person, in a single array, with hundreds of generations (and also imagine each 'parent' can have infinite kids rather than 2.5 :)

Currently my only exposure with arrays are in php, and javascript, so they would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It is very general question, and cannot be answered in proper way. Of course different languages works with arrays differently, php uses hashmaps (which are quite slow in comparison to c/c++ for example), javascript AFAIK uses ordinary arrays (so, they should have comparable performance with c/c++), java has ordinary arrays, hashmaps, linkedlists and so on.

The second part is about storing such data (I suppose database), in relational db (mysql) you can store them as trees (see [Hierarchical data in RDBMSs](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/links/#hierarchical)), or you can just have many-to-many link via 2 tables (person, link table)

In any case - the main answer to your questions will be found during deep investigation of **what operations you're planning to do** - this will define data structure you should use and way you store this structure to disk.

If we suppose "family tree" - what do you want to do with it? just display, or maybe search, or maybe some statistical findings (like how many sons were born in this family by years?), maybe we need to compute relation between 2 different persons (like cousins), etc.

Notice: don't forget that 1 child can have more that 2 parents (in case of step and god fathers).